# mySQL query returns wrong result

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to calculate the current balance from the the odds, status and the stake.

Status = 'wrong' or 'correct'

odds = for instance 1.70

stake = fixed 100

So the calculations would be something like

```
If status = wrong THEN
balance = balance - 100
ELSE
balance = balance + (odds * 100 - 100)
END
```

I've tried to implement this in my query and it seem to work however it gives the wrong result in the balance column.

My query:

```
    SET @balance = 0;
     SELECT odds.meta_value AS odds, stat.meta_value AS stats, 
                CASE WHEN stat.meta_value =  'wrong'
                THEN @balance := @balance -100
                ELSE @balance := @balance + ( odds.meta_value * 100 - 100 ) 
                END as balance
                FROM wp_t3a673_posts posts
                LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_postmeta stat ON posts.ID = stat.post_id
                AND stat.meta_key =  'status'
                LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_postmeta odds ON posts.ID = odds.post_id
                AND odds.meta_key =  'odds'
                LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_term_relationships tr ON posts.ID = tr.object_id
                LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_term_taxonomy t ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id
                WHERE (
                stat.meta_value =  'correct'
                OR stat.meta_value =  'wrong'
                )
                AND posts.post_status =  'publish'
                AND t.taxonomy =  'category'
                AND (
                t.term_id =4
                OR t.term_id =5
                OR t.term_id =6
                )
        ORDER BY posts.id
```

The output here is

```
1.70    wrong   105
3.05    correct 205
2.20    correct 225
1.33    correct 258
1.35    correct 293
1.38    correct 231
2.32    wrong   193
```

So because the balance calculations is wrong i decided to try and make a SQLFiddle, to test the data with the exact same order, data and balance sql calculations and what you will see is this calculations is correct. What is the reason why my query is not showing this result as in the sqlfiddle?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea13c/1

Comment: mysql and sql server are not the same.Maybe check for triggers?

Comment: Okay i narrowed it down to that it calculate the balance before it orders by id and therefor it doing wrong calculations? What can i do to order before calculating balance?

Comment: You have to divide your statement. Build a subquery

Comment: I'm not sure i understand could you make an example in and answer?